# Access JSON object with whitespace and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON object from https://api.myjson.com/bins/1e3d19

```
[
  {
    "commit 0": "2017-07-22T19:36:50.000+12:00"
  },
  {
    "commit 1": "2017-07-22T14:46:40.000+12:00"
  },
  {
    "commit 2": "2017-07-21T22:46:18.000+12:00"
  },
  {
    "commit 3": "2017-07-20T19:32:10.000+12:00"
  },
  {
    "commit 4": "2017-07-19T17:50:29.000+12:00"
  },
  {
    "commit 5": "2017-07-19T16:00:50.000+12:00"
  }
]
```

Im trying to display/store it in a variable. The problem is I cant access it as it have white space. I have tried something like this. Its returning "undefined 0" cause `console.log[object.commit+ " " }[i]` means getting the object that has name "commit" only not `commit 1`. I might be overthinking here and there could be a simple solution. Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
  async: true,
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1e3d19",
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, object) {
      console.log(object.commit+ " "+[i]);
    });
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWjKQb

Answer (score 2):

You can access it (only) using the [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects):

> However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"commit 0": "2017-07-22T19:36:50.000+12:00"}');
console.log(obj['commit 0']);
```